# Is it possible to write the same permutation as a collection of disjoint cycles in two different ways?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is apparently no. I just don't get it.

$(1, 2, 3)(4, 5)$ and $(2, 3, 1)(5, 4)$ are the same permutation. Aren't those $2$ different ways of writing the same permutation?

Comment: This is a good question!  Not necessarily because it's a difficult matter, but because it cuts right to the center of your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that they are the same permutation. This is not a contradiction; you simply wrote the same cycles in two different ways. $(231)=(123)$ and $(54)=(45)$. This is because $231$ is a cyclic permutation of 123 and 45 is a cyclic permutation of 54. You get 231 from 123 by shifting everything to the left by one place (then the 1 ends up at the end).

"Rearrangement" here refers to rearranging the order of the cycles themselves, not the elements within the cycles.

Comment: So then what does "Every permutation of a finite set can be expressed as a collection of pairwise disjoint cycles. Furthermore, this representation is **unique up to rearranging the cycles and the cyclic order of the elements within cycles**" mean? Does it mean (345) is unique till we rewrite it as (354)?

Comment: 354 is not a cyclic permutation of 345. The cyclic permutations of 345 are 345, 453, 534. You are only allowed to shift the numbers, you can't swap them.

Comment: What does the part in bold of the theorem above mean? Maybe I am misunderstanding that part.

Comment: It means that if you change the order that you write the cycles, or if you shift the numbers within the cycles cyclically, the permutation remains the same. Any other changes will give you a different permutation.

Comment: Then, (679)(345) is unique unless we rewrite it as (354)(967), yes? Elements in (354)(967) are not shifted cyclically, just swapped.

Comment: $(679)(345)\neq (354)(967)$ because although $(967)=(679)$, $(354)\neq (345)$. You have written the unique cycle decompositions of two different permutations.

Comment: I get it now. But the part in bold doesn't say anything about swapping vs shifting, just rearranging which could mean either swapping or shifting. How does one infer these things? Is there more standard way of writing the part in bold?

Comment: "rearranging the cycles" refers to changing the order of the sequence of whole cycles, not the elements within the cycles, and that reordering is arbitrary. "rearranging the cyclic order within the cycles" ---key word here is "cyclic"-- means re-ordering inside the cycle as if the elements were written in a clockwise circle and then just changing the starting point.

Comment: This does it. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

The misconception is that $(1\ 2\ 3)$ is different from $(2\ 3\ 1)$. Although the markup looks different, they represent the *exact same* cycle. In the same manner we have $(4\ 5) = (5\ 4)$.
To get a somewhat unique *representation* of the cycles, you have to impose a condition on the markup, for example to start with the smallest element (wich is not mapped to itself). Then the canonical representation would in fact be your first one, since $1$ is the smallest element of $(1\ 2\ 3)$ and $4$ is the smallest element of $(4\ 5)$.

Comment: You also need to impose an order on the cycles.

Comment: @vadim123 Not for individual cycles. For the factors of a permutation you are correct. This could again be done by taking the minimal starting element of a cycle as its sorting order.